# Script to fire fn + f6 every time computer starts?

Tags: windows, script, automation

My laptop's touchpad has malfunctioned. Every time I start the computer, I have to manually press the keys <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f6</kbd> to shut it off. How can I create a script which does this automatically on every start?

Comment: Why don't you just disable it in Device manager?

Comment: Because it's easier to enable/disable it via Fn+F6. He just wants it to start disabled.

Comment: Do you have any touchpad related settings available in the BIOS? You might be able to disable it entirely from there.

Comment: @and31415 Unfortunately there is no touchpad related settings in BIOS.

Comment: @DaveRook I would prefer not doing that as edvinas.me suggested. Besides there is no option to disable it in the context menu.

Comment: @Aster he means disable it in device manager, not BIOS. There's always an entry for the touch pad in device manager http://www.pcworld.com/article/241048/how_to_disable_your_laptop_touchpad.html

Comment: What's the laptop exact model? Also, what's the operating system?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Yes I know that and I there is no "disable" option in the context menu in device manager when I right click on the device's entry.

Comment: @and31415 Lenovo y510p, OS Windows 8.1

Comment: why not? I've never seen a case like this. Anyway you can always go to control panel > mouse (or right click the touchpad button on notification area) and disable it like [this](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_eW8Uemxxm60/S8F1h57gxcI/AAAAAAAAAGc/yZ_X_D6l4pU/s1600/Synaptic-Config.png). For other touchpad types (such as Elan), there's also a similar function http://t-issariyakul.blogspot.com/2010/04/synaptics-disabling-touch-page-gestures.html

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc That did it. I had to go to the manufacturer's website to download and install it and thus find the option to disable it. It would be nice however if what I wish to do can be done via script.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's answered in the comments

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: It looks like your comment provided the answer to this question, but the OP is long gone.  Could you post the solution as an answer to close the loop on this question?

Comment: @Dave: If the answer being in the comments was a basis for closure, half of the questions would be closed.  This was an on-topic problem and it had a solution.  If it turned out to have been a hiccup and wasn't reproducible, that would be a basis for closure.